nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex does not return NVML_SUCCESS

OS: Windows
CUDA version: 11.5
GPU Driver version: 531.79

I have two graphics cards on my PC: GPU 0 is Intel UHD Graphics 770, and GPU 1 is GeForce RTX 3060.
I’m developing an application that uses NVML (NVIDIA Management Library) to interact with NVIDIA GPUs. To ensure NVML works correctly, I tested it using a sample code from the NVIDIA GPU Deployment Kit:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nvml.h>

const char* convertToComputeModeString(nvmlComputeMode_t mode) {
    switch (mode) {
        case NVML_COMPUTEMODE_DEFAULT:
            return "Default";
        case NVML_COMPUTEMODE_EXCLUSIVE_THREAD:
            return "Exclusive_Thread";
        case NVML_COMPUTEMODE_PROHIBITED:
            return "Prohibited";
        case NVML_COMPUTEMODE_EXCLUSIVE_PROCESS:
            return "Exclusive Process";
        default:
            return "Unknown";
    }
}

int main() {
    nvmlReturn_t result;
    unsigned int device_count, i;

    // Initialize NVML library
    result = nvmlInit();
    if (NVML_SUCCESS != result) {
        printf("Failed to initialize NVML: %s\n", nvmlErrorString(result));
        return 1;
    }

    // Query the number of NVIDIA devices
    result = nvmlDeviceGetCount(&device_count);
    if (NVML_SUCCESS != result) {
        printf("Failed to query device count: %s\n", nvmlErrorString(result));
        nvmlShutdown();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Found %d device%s\n\n", device_count, device_count != 1 ? "s" : "");

    // List and query details of each device
    printf("Listing devices:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < device_count; i++) {
        nvmlDevice_t device;
        char name[NVML_DEVICE_NAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
        nvmlPciInfo_t pci;
        nvmlComputeMode_t compute_mode;

        // Get handle for the device
        result = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(i, &device);
        if (NVML_SUCCESS != result) {
            printf("Failed to get handle for device %i: %s\n", i, nvmlErrorString(result));
            nvmlShutdown();
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Shutdown NVML library
    nvmlShutdown();
    return 0;
}

Upon running this program, I receive the following output:
Found 1 device
Listing devices:
Failed to get handle for device 0: Not Supported

It appears that all functionalities work except for nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(). Any suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
I've looked online for a similar issue, but I couldn't find anything that was relevant or helpful. I've also gone through the documentation, but it doesn't explain what "Not Supported" means in this particular case.
